# creating a hierarchical tree structure of images in html5 canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, mouseover

There is a tree hierarchical relation between a group of images, I want images to be represented as a tree structure in canvas tag with child node images smaller than parent node images and all the images should scale up with some value on mouseover.

The setscale and translate javascript functions let me do the scaling effect all right but I cannot get mouse event listener functions working right, mouseover and mouseout are not being detected although the images are displayed. I do not get the alert messages I have used for debugging. This is just a test code:-

```
     function loadImages(sources, callback){
       var images = {};
       var loadedImages = 0;
       var numImages = 0;
       // get num of sources
       for (var src in sources) {
        numImages++;
       }
       for (var src in sources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function(){
            if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                callback(images);
            }
        };
        images[src].src = sources[src];
       }
       }  
 
 
 
    window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var destX = 20;
    var destY = 20;
    var destWidth = 200;
    var destHeight = 137;
    
    var sources = new Array();
    sources[0]="darth-vader.jpg";
    sources[1]="darth-vader.jpg";
    
    var imageObj = new Image();
 
    loadImages(sources, function(images){
        context.drawImage(images[0], destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
         images[0].onmouseover=function()
        {
            alert('1');
        }

        images[0].onmouseout=function()
        {
            alert('2');
        }
        context.drawImage(images[1], destX+200,destY, destWidth, destHeight);
        images[1].onmouseover=function()
        {
            alert('3');
        }

        images[1].onmouseout=function()
        {
            alert('4');
        }
          });
         };
```

Comment: You're drawing a copy of the image on the canvas. The `onmouseover` attributes only work on the image *element*, which you haven't made visible. To get something like this working, you'll have to implement detection as to where the cursor and the images are.

Comment: by image element do you mean the html image tag? If yes, can i get that working with the canvas tag?

Comment: Yes, `new Image` basically creates an image tag. You can't "just" have this tag placed on a canvas. You can only draw the visual representation on the canvas. You'd have to use `canvas.onmouseover` and determine whether the cursor is in the image with some maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are triggered on dom elements not on images painted on a canvas. If you want to simulate those events try to set a mousemove event on the canvas and then if the mouse is inside the area where you have drawn the image trigger the mouseover.

Comment: Iam a total noob to html5 and canvas, can you please suggest how to detect in which particular image is the mouse over if at all it is over some image?

Comment: If I have two images, A and B, which I intend to draw onto the canvas, I should take note of their intended position on the canvas, their dimensions, etc. before I draw them: `A.x = 7; A.y = 195; A.width = 120; A.height = 60;`. Then when the canvas is clicked, I check if the mouse click (x, y) falls within the bounds of any objects I've drawn. There are certainly more efficient algorithms, but this is the gist of the idea.

Comment: Btw, when I say "objects" here, I really mean a loose association of two or three different things. You're thinking of the "object" as the thing that exists on the canvas, but that's wrong. The canvas is just a bunch of pixels (ever copy-and-paste a photo into MS paint? same idea). The "bounds" I mentioned are just the numbers you bothered to save somewhere. The image is the original image object you "copied" onto the canvas. No connection between all these except what you create yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can only put mouse events on the canvas itself, not on the images drawn to it.

You're going to have to start keeping track of the size and location of images drawn so you can do relevant things when the user clicks on the canvas. See [A Gentle Introduction to Making Canvas Useful](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) for examples of how to keep track of multiple selectable objects on a canvas.